# Apache and IIS sharing same SSL certificate

Tags: apache, iis, configuration, ssl-certificate

I have two applications (PHP and .NET) working on the same machine but different servers (one on Apache and one on IIS). I also have SSL certificate used by PHP application. I would like my .NET app to work on the same domain name and use the same certificate.

How should I configure my servers?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTPS only verifies the host name when checking a certificate (see [RFC 2818 Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1)), not the port, so you shouldn't have any problem using the same certificate for two different applications on the same host.

You could have:

- Apache Httpd on `https://www.example.com/` (port 443, default)
- IIS on `https://www.example.com:8443/` (port 8443)

Where it's going to be a problem is if you want to use the same port for Apache Httpd and IIS. It's not necessarily a good idea to have a different server running on a non-standard port for HTTPS: it may cause problems since some firewalls (and some proxy servers) will not let you connect to HTTPS on another port than 443 (or at least, port 8443 won't be open).

A solution to this is to use Apache Httpd as a front-end and forward a "section" of the request (e.g. eveything starting with `https://www.example.com/iis/`) to IIS in the back. This can be done using a reverse proxy (see `mod_proxy_http` in Apache Httpd). If your IIS server is on the same machine, the redirection can effectively go to `localhost` (on the port of your choice for IIS, maybe not the default 80). In this case, the connection between Apache Httpd and IIS don't need to be secured with SSL/TLS, so you wouldn't need to set up a certificate for IIS (you can if you really want to, but it's not useful on `localhost` connections). All SSL/TLS connections from the users would end at Apache Httpd, which would then dispatch internally some request to IIS in the back.

There might be more documentation generally available about this when putting Apache Tomcat (or a Java container) behind Apache Httpd, but the principles should be the same when replacing Tomcat with IIS.

Here is some documentation about Apache Httpd with Jetty: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_mod_proxy#Configuring_Apache_mod_proxy_with_Jetty

From Apache Httpd's point of view using IIS instead of Jetty should be very similar. You may have to tweak the IIS configuration to make it pretend its incoming requests come over HTTPS (since they will come over plain HTTP), if some of your IIS apps are configured to require this.

I think IIS also has reverse-proxy capabilities, so if this approach is too tricky, you should be able to reverse the roles. Look for using IIS as your HTTPS entry point and putting your Apache/PHP application in the back.

Comment: This is an amazingly awesome answer!

Comment: IIS can act as a reverse proxy for Apache HTTPD, Apache Tomcat, and probably others using it's Application Request Routing (ARR) module. There may be better options for configuring your setup but if you need IIS to route the incoming requests ARR does work. The current link to it is http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing.

Answer (score 1):

A SSL is mostly registered to a fully qualified domain name e.g. www.mydomain.com

Unless you have a wildcard SSL, so unless you have the IIS and appache serving the exact same domain e.g. www.mydomain.com, which would be strange as you would end up with conflicts when running a request to said domain.

But installing a SSL on IIS just follow the guide below.
IIS7 http://www.globalsign.com/support/install/install_iis7.php
IIS5 + 6 h[ttp://www.globalsign.com/support/install/install_iis5.php](http://www.globalsign.com/support/install/install_iis5.php)

Comment: I found the solution of configuring reverse proxy on Apache but there are some problems with redirecting requests to IIS on the same machine. Reverse proxy should work in my case.